# Different behaviour on Arrays.asList(T...) using ternary

Tags: java

A colleague came across this behaviour while using ternary operator inside the `Arrays.asList(T...)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {              
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"2"}));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(false? new int []{2} :new String[]{"2"}));
}
```

The first sout prints: `[2]`

The second one prints: `[[Ljava.lang.String;@36baf30c]`

The java version used is java 8.

Shouldn't the second sout print the same result as the  first?

Comment: this `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(false ? new Integer[]{2} : new String[]{"2"}));` worked for me

Comment: Another way of saying what khelwood said is that Java has a static typing system.  The type passed to `Arrays.asList()` has to be resolved at compile time.  In the first case the type is `String[]` and the `asList` method functions as expected.  In the second case it has to use `Object` because it can't dynamically at runtime guess which type is going to be used.  (And despite the constant `false` being used, I think the Java typing system requires it to use this behavior and not optimize away the rest of the expression.  So at least the behavior is consistent.)

Answer (score 8):

`Arrays.asList` has varargs parameter, and it can be called in two ways:

1. you pass it an array of some kind of objects and those objects become the contents of the list.
2. you pass zero or more objects and they are put into an array, and then they become the contents of your list.

The first version of your code

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"2"}))
```

is interpreted as you passing a String array in place of the varargs argument to `asList`, so you get a String list containing the contents of the array, which is the element "2".

In the second version, the type of the expression

```
(false? new int []{2} :new String[]{"2"})
```

is Object, since `int[]` and `String[]` have no other common base type, and an int array cannot be interpreted as an Object array.

So your `asList` call resolves to a varargs call with one Object argument.

That gives you a list containing one element, where that element itself is your array.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of Arrays.asList is a varargs parameter, `T...`, which is syntactic sugar that lets you call it in either of two ways:

- You can call it with an expression of type `T[]`, in which case the result of that expression is passed directly into Arrays.asList.

  - This is what you're doing in your first case: the argument has type `String[]`, so `T` is `String` and the array is passed into Arrays.asList.
- You can call it with zero or more expressions of type `T`, in which case the results of those expressions get bundled up into an array which gets passed into Arrays.asList.

  - This is what you're doing in your second case: the argument has type `Object`, so `T` is `Object` and a single-element array *containing* that argument gets passed into Arrays.asList.

This is because `int` isn't a subtype of `Object`, so `int[]` isn't a subtype of `Object[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Arrays.asList` takes a "variable arity" parameter of type `T...`, it can be called in two ways:

- With an explicit array, like `Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1", "2"})`
- With any number of array elements, like `Arrays.asList("1", "2")`

These two expressions result in equivalent lists. When the method is called with just one argument, Java decides whether to treat it like the former (an explicit array) or the latter (as a singleton in an implicit array) based on the argument's type: if it's an array then it's passed directly, otherwise a new array is created containing that single element.

Importantly, because Java has static binding (which is distinct from dynamic dispatch), the decision is made using the compile-time type of the argument, not its type at runtime:

- The expression `new String[] {"1"}` has compile-time type `String[]`, so it is passed directly as an array, hence you get a list containing one string.
- However, the expression `false ? new int[] {2} : new String[] {"2"}` has compile-time type `Object`, since that is the least upper bound of the two operand types `int[]` and `String[]`, so it is passed as an element in a new singleton array, hence you get a list containing an array containing one string.